# Put all drawable folder images directly in arraylist

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am developing an android game app and I have more then 150 images inside my app!
I want to put all images which exist in drawable package in a ArrayList.
I have this code

```
InputStream ips = getAssets().open("Arrow001.jpg");
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ips, null);
        questionImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

but i don't want to add them one by one in myArray and i want to use a loop for generate images in arrayList when i run my app!

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are they all named Arrow001.jpg, Arrow002.jpg, Arrow003.jpg and so on and so forth?

Comment: I afraid you'll face with memory issue.

Comment: @ChrisS No the names are defferrent!

Comment: @Aleksandr The images are really in small size! but if i have issue about that, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get array of all assets files on root assets folder by calling

```
String[] list = getAssets().list("")
```

In our case you can write code like below.

```
for (String assetPath : getAssets().list("")) {
    InputStream ips = getAssets().open(assetPath);
    //yours code
}
```